# Folder named `xyz` appears under the name `Public Desktop` in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, filesystems

In Windows 8:
I have a folder that is currently named 'unused' but the same behavior occurs with any name that I rename it to. The name appears correctly in CMD when I type dir but when I look for the folder in Windows Explorer I always see the name `Public Desktop` instead of the actual folder name. CMD will show the real name of the folder and will change as well if I rename the folder in Windows Explorer. The Windows Explorer continues to show the folder with the name 'Public Desktop'.

Things I did:

1. I renamed the folder several times.
2. I reset the machine several times.

These did not help.

[image]

Comment: You will never be able to remove Chuck Norris! (I know this doesn't help but I just wanted to say that)

Comment: @EricF Maybe Chuck Norris feels the folder is more aptly named Public Desktop in the Windows Explorer? :o

Comment: The system does not control Chuck Norris. Chuck Norris IS the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It most likely caused by a "Localized Resource Name" entry in the `desktop.ini` file inside that "unused" folder.

The easiest way to deal with it in this case is to just delete the existing `desktop.ini` file.

Explorer:

- Enable viewing hidden and system files.
- Navigate to that folder.
- Delete `desktop.ini` file.

Command prompt:

```
cd\dataspace\garbage
attrib desktop.ini -h -s
del desktop.ini
```

You (may) need to log off and log in again to restart Explorer (or just kill and restart the Explorer.exe process) to have it take effect.

Comment: Nope, worked right away, just need to delete the file like you said. Once you spelled it out, it made perfect sense cause I did move some files around and amongst them dektop.ini files. You sir are pretty awesome.

Comment: What is the significance of the change you made to my question? I see you added some square brackets around the image description thing?

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite Sorry, should have noted it I guess. :) Adding the extra [][#] reference around the picture place holder makes it a clickable link (to the same image), so that I (and others) can click it to open it in a new browser window full sized, and actually read it. ;)

Comment: cool thanks! I was just wondering out of curiosity